# Centos fonts

Tags: centos, tomcat, font, ghostscript

I am using inkscape/gs on a Cent OS 5 server.  Where do I need to put the fonts so that inkscape, which uses gs, will be able to find the fonts when it is rendering a pdf or ps file from a svg?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to put them into your ~/.fonts directory.

Comment: this is for a tomcat installation.  I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use them system wide, you should put them in /usr/share/fonts. That's where X.org stores it's fonts and that is where other applications will expect them to be.

The Tomcat requirement would have been nice in your initial question, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command `gs -h`. This will return a little help screen, indicating 3 different areas:

- some possible commandline switches for gs;
- a list of builtin "devices" (=drivers) which may be used with `"-sDEVICE=..."`;
- a list of "search paths", some of which will obviously be font related.

Take a close look at these search paths. This is where **your** version of Ghostscript will look for fonts. So the easiest way would be to stuff the fonts which you want to be used by Ghostscript into one of these directories. If the directory does not exist, simply create it. Or create a symlink that points "from-where-gs-searches" to "where-the-fonts-are".

Of course, you can also add a parameter

```
"-I/path/to/one/font/directory:/another/path/to/second/fontdir"
```

to the commandline calling Ghostscript (I don't know, though, if Inkscape allows you to set up the exact gs command it uses....)